# Setting HTML element attribute conditionally

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-class, angularjs-material

I have a data table that is in-line editable. One of the columns that is editable is an md-input field. I can easily enough add `md-maxlength="80"` to show the character counter. Given that this data table is done with UI-Grid (that code isn't relevant here), it applies the counter to all md-inputs in that column. What I really want is it to only show the character counter on focus. This is using Angular 1.X.

Ive got this so far, but I dont know if the expression to `ng-class` can accept anything except CSS classes.

```
<md-input
    ng-init="focused=false"
    ng-class="{'md-maxlength=80': focused}"
    ng-focus="focused=true"
    ng-blur="focused=false"
    ...
</md-input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to add the `md-maxlength="80"` attribute when `focused` is `true`.  Right now you are attempting to set the attribute as a CSS class which would make no sense since you can't have `<div class="myClass md-maxlength='80'">`

Why not just set the value of the `md-maxlenth` property conditionally?  Set the value to `80` when `focused=true` and set it to `null` otherwise.  Possibly set it to `0` or some other value that makes sense for the `md-input` control since I'm not familiar with it.

```html
<md-input
    ng-init="focused=false"
    md-maxlength="focused ? 80 : null"
    ng-focus="focused=true"
    ng-blur="focused=false"
    ...
</md-input>
```